# Secret forum visible only to users of a specific role

Tags: nodes

I need to create a forum that is visible to only users with a specific role. It should remain hidden to other users including registered users. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Try the [Forum Access](http://drupalmodules.com/module/forum-access) module.